# Getting the "The MD5 signature could not be verified." on a Worldpay FuturePay installation

Tags: php, md5, digital-signature, worldpay

I am getting this error message (`"The MD5 signature could not be verified."`) when trying to use a **FuturePay** installation (sending an MD5 hash as the signature field). If I try to send the form without the signature tells me:
`"The installation ID field is blank or contains invalid characters.
A different submission protocol is required. A more secure submission may be required.
The installation number is invalid."`

I have to mention that I tried to use the signatureFields field (I am getting the same error) and that for the normal Junior installation it works like a charm.

I also must say that the way **WorldPay** presents the installations is very confusing. While they advice `"A more secure submission may be required"` when not using the MD5 signature there is no place in the admin area to set one.

I am still assuming that it's the same that you set for the Junior installation.

Comment: Show us how you compute the signature, please. Parameter ordering is important.

Comment: for the normal Junior installation, which works just fine, I am doing this:       `<input type="hidden" name="signatureFields" value="instId:cartId" />
 <input type="hidden"name="signature" value="<?php echo md5((string)WORLDPAY_TEST_MD5_STRING . ':' . WORLDPAY_TEST_INSTALLATION_ID . ':' . 'abc123'); ?>">`

Comment: If WORLDPAY_TEST_MD5_STRING is your API secret, WORLDPAY_TEST_INSTALLATION_ID is your installation ID (instId) **and** is also present as a field in clear text, and abc123 is your cartId **and is also present as a field in clear text, then it should work.

Comment: By the way thank you for answering so quick! That's is what I thought too: that it should work, but unfortunately for FuturePay it doesn't. And the error messages I am getting from WorldPay are too generic.

Comment: Can you put your form on a fiddle (jsfiddle.net), obfuscating your secret beforehand?

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error only using my installation id which I cannot share but here is the form: https://jsfiddle.net/dbzpatre - using the worldpay test example

Comment: So... `WORLDPAY_TEST_INSTALLATION_ID` = 211621? If not, there's your issue. Check while you're at it that your secret is actually for that install.

Comment: Note that the [tag:signature] is not correct as that's about *method* signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that you are using the correct type of installation, I believe there are two types of FuturePay - one for website integration purposes and another which can only be used via the WorldPay dashboard.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what it was happening. Forgot to mention that the installation I have is called FuturePayDirect. They told me that I need a different type of installation simply called FuturePay.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that the hex encoded representation of the hash has to be lower case

Valid

```
94c439ad99c6afd9b1db69b3e77f9c3b
```

Invalid

```
94C439AD99C6AFD9B1DB69B3E77F9C3B
```